# What is the process named "sh"

Tags: c, linux

In Linux, I compile a C program that includes
`system("ps");`

I expect when my program runs, system("ps") code print three program. which is "bash", "ps" and "a.out"
but the result is "bash", "ps", "a.out" and "sh"
[ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU75A.png)

I know that sh and bash are the kinds of shell.
but why "sh" added when I run my program?

Comment: `man 3 system` should answer your question.

Comment: Did you search the web or this site before asking?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I agree with you. I misinterpreted the question. Thus, I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`man system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html):

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>        The  system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in com‐
>        mand using execl(3) as follows:
>
>            execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
>
>        system() returns after the command has been completed.
> ```

The `system()` function starts a shell and passes the `command` string as parameter in order for it to be executed under the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what [the function you used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) does:

> Calls the host environment's command processor with the parameter `command`.

And from the [Linux manpage for `system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html):

> The `system()` library function uses `fork(2)` to create a child process       that executes the shell command specified in command using `execl(3)` as follows:
>
> ```
> execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
> ```

Read the documentation for functions you use, especially when they're doing something you did not expect. That's why the documentation exists: for you to read.

Answer (score 0):

using `system` you do not directly launch one program/command with its argument like with `execv` but you give a line of command(s) given to `sh` like if you enter them by hand in that shell

so for instance you can do `system("date;ps")`

As the manual says `system(command)` does :

```
 execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sh` is the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell). You see it because `system` forks and then `/bin/sh` with the command provided in the parameter. See [system's man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) for additional details.